# Play! Framework shared folder between VM and Host not triggering webhook

Tags: linux, windows, playframework, virtual-machine

I've ran into an awkward issue. I'll try and explain this as best as I can so bare with.

I'm running Play! on a Linux VM (Oracle VirtualBox), with `sbt run` command in my terminal it works perfectly fine. If I use an IDE on my VM the webhook catches the change and does a reload.

I've shared a folder between my Host (Windows) and my VM (Linux) where my project directory is. I've also extended a port so that I can open my Play! web application on the Windows machine.

On my Windows Host machine I'm running an IDE (IntelliJ) and when I change something on a file, the Play! webhook running on my VM doesn't seem to pick up the changes made, even though it's listening for changes in my shared folder.

> Question: Is there some sort of configuration or share folder magic
>   trick to get my Play! application to pick up the changes made from the
>   Host machine?

Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inotify does not work on VMWare's shared folder. You might be able to convince SBT's filewatcher to use polling, but that doesn't work really well.

Comment: I found something on googles play group about using sbt ~run instead of sbt run. That seems to compile but not reload the changes..